# How to calculate the number of days between two given dates

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, datetime

```
import csv

f = csv.reader(open('lmt.csv', 'r'))         # open input file for reading
Date, Open, Hihh, mLow, Close, Volume = zip(*f)    # split it into separate columns
```

Now I want to pick two dates out of the `Date` column and calculate the number of days between them. 
Sadly, because they are retrieved from a .csv file, they are in "'\xef\xbb\xbfDate'" format.

So when I attempted to use `datetime` module, it didn't work.

One thing I can think of is have excel do the calculation by means of `=DATEDIF(A2, B2, "d")` but I'd love to have a more elegant solution.

Comment: What didn't work when you used date time?

Comment: Is `'\xef\xbb\xbfDate'` an actual example of content of the date column? If so, what date would that represent?

Comment: Don't use capital letters in variable names. Otherwise they look like class names.

Comment: please provide a sample of input data

Comment: search for "how to get rid of UTF-8 BOM in Python"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a follow-up of [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527861/how-to-choose-which-column-to-write-in-csv-in-python/35528088#35528088) to one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35527861/how-to-choose-which-column-to-write-in-csv-in-python) (where one also finds the link to the data file), the following will work fine. The code below will calculate the amount of days between `df['Date'][0]` ('17-Feb-16') and `df['Date'][10]` ('2-Feb-16'). The output you receive is:

> The difference are 15 days.

Here is the code with a couple of inline comments:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('lmt.csv')

# get rid of the format issue
df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]: 'Date' }, inplace=True)

# define your format in the Date column
date_format = '%d-%b-%y'

# select the first date
date1 = datetime.strptime(df['Date'][0], date_format)

# select the second date
date2 = datetime.strptime(df['Date'][10], date_format)

# calculate the difference between the dates
diffDates = date1 - date2

# print results in days
print 'The difference are ' + str(diffDates.days) + ' days.'
```

If you want the output not in days but in hours, you can check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119472/convert-a-timedelta-to-days-hours-and-minutes).

**EDIT**

For the new file you need:

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
```

Then it works just fine. Check [this link](http://strftime.org/) for a detailed explanation of the different formats.

Comment: sorry about this but for some reason when i download the spreadsheet now from http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=YHOO  (its yahoo instead of lockheed now) the formatting for the dates doesnt work anymore, i guess you have to modify '%d-%b-%y' not sure what im supposed to do with this (i know your code above works for the original 'lmt' file so your code works but this is just a follow up question..)

Comment: BTW: Did you accidentally downvote my other answer when you accepted it? It happened at the same time, so I am just wondering...